# How can i create an array if it doesn't exist and run a jquery function after it creates an array?

Tags: jquery

I have a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rayd360/Qbxee/).

I want to be able to check if an array exists. If it does not exist i need to create it and run a this function.

```
$('p').live('click', function(){
    $('p').html('yay, it worked! Thankyou!')
}
```

That does not work and i know that but i do not know how to check it.

Comment: what do you mean "does not exists" ?

Comment: Not entirely sure what the array thing is about, but here's your code working – you missed out the closing bracket. http://jsfiddle.net/Qbxee/1/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a normal `if` statement instead of the conditional operator:

```
if(!$.isArray(x)) {
    x = [];
    $('p').live('click', function(){
        $('p').html('yay, it worked! Thankyou!')
    });
}
```

*Note: `x` must be at least declared (`var x;`) for this to work.*

**Reference**: [`if...else`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else), [`jQuery.isArray`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isArray/)

**Update:** Reading the comments on the other (now deleted answer), did you intend to do something like this?

```
function doStuff() {
    $('p').html('yay, it worked! Thankyou!');
}

$('p').live('click', doStuff);

if(!$.isArray(x)) {
    x = [];
    doStuff();
}
```

It's not really clear given the information you provided. You just said *run this function* and posted a snippet which lets assume that the whole snippet is the code you want to run when the array is created. Please be more precise.

Comment: this is an excellent answer and i like it but it does not seem to actually work