# How does this shorthand statement actually work? "x = ( typeof x != 'undefined' && x instanceof Array ) ? x : [];"

Tags: javascript

```
x = ( typeof x != 'undefined' && x instanceof Array ) ? x : [];
```

I understand that if x is defined and it is an array it will do everything between ? and : then if undefined or it is not an array it will do []. what is []?

Does anyone know where i can get examples of how this works and other shorthand techniques or can you explain what is happening here?

I just really dont understand how it is creating an array

Comment: `[]` is an *array literal*. I suggest to read the [MDN JavaScript Guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide), especially about [literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Values%2C_Variables%2C_and_Literals#Literals).

Comment: `typeof x != 'undefined' &&` is redundant btw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`[]` is an empty array.

So if `x` is `undefined` or not an array, then it is set to an empty array.

This is the same as:

```
if (!( typeof x != 'undefined' && x instanceof Array )) {
    x = [];
}
```

There is more information on the *Conditional (Ternary) Operator* here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx

Another useful shorthand for default arguments is:

```
function (x) {
    x = x || 7;
}
```

This is set `x` to `7` as long as `x == false` (i.e. `x` is not `null`, `undefined`, `false`, `''` (empty string), or `0`)

Comment: so if i was wanting to run a function if x is an array i would do this: x = ( typeof x != 'undefined' && x instanceof Array ) ? functionName(); : []; is that correct?

Comment: @user1082764: Only if you wanted to *assign* the return value of `functionName()` to `x`. The conditional operator should only be used for variable assignments. Use a normal `if` statement instead (like I told you in my answer [to your previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9490555/how-can-i-create-an-array-if-it-doesnt-exist-and-run-a-jquery-function-after-it)).

Comment: this was EXTREAMLEY helpful. I have asked questions here but never had this thorough of an answer. Thank you!

Comment: If x is an Array instance from another global scope (e.g. an iFrame), then `x instanceof Array` will return false because it has a different `Array.prototype` on its `[[Prototype]]` chain. Also, an object can have `Array.prototype` on its `[[Prototype]]` chain but not be a "real" array.